# JComo hacer que un do while cierre ciclo al escribir "fin" al preguntarme por un string, pero que no vuelva a entrar al ciclo de nuevo al escribirlo

Tags: java

LENGUAJE: JAVA

Buenas, estoy haciendo un ejercicio de examen de años anteriores que me envió un amigo que está un año mas adelantado, pero estoy teniendo problemas con un do while que no cierra al yo escribir la condición de corte ("fin")en el input deseado ("patente"). Espero que puedan ayudarme a resolverlo. Se que es posible hacerlo con un while, pero eso implicaría añadir mas líneas de código. exclusivamente tiene que ser hecho con do while, aqui les dejo una imagen del enunciado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
package Ejercitacion;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class prueba2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String patente, vehiculo;
        final int COSTO_MOTO = 50, COSTO_AUTO = 100 , COSTO_CAMIONETA = 150;
        int cont_motos = 0, cont_autos = 0, cont_camionetas = 0, cont_patentes = 0;
        int hora = 0, total_vehiculos = 0, recaudacion_total;
        int porcentaje_autos, valoraCobrarAutoPico = 0, valoraCobrarAuto = 0, valoraCobrarMotoPico = 0, valoraCobrarMoto = 0, valoraCobrarCamioneta = 0, valoraCobrarCamionetaPico = 0;
        boolean esMoto, esAuto, esCamioneta;
        
        
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese la patente: ");
            patente = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Que tipo de vehiculo es? 'a', 'm' o 'c'");
            vehiculo = input.nextLine();
            if(esAuto = (vehiculo.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))) {
                System.out.println("A que hora paso este auto? (0-23): ");
                hora = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                while(hora < 0 || hora > 23) {
                    System.out.println("El horario debe ser entre 0 y 23: ");
                    hora = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                }
                if(hora >= 9 && hora <= 18) {
                    valoraCobrarAutoPico = (((COSTO_AUTO*50)/100)+COSTO_AUTO);
                    System.out.println("Se le cobrará: " + valoraCobrarAutoPico);
                }else {
                        valoraCobrarAuto = (COSTO_AUTO);
                        System.out.println("Se le cobrará: " + valoraCobrarAuto);
                }
                cont_autos++;
            }
            if(esMoto = (vehiculo.equalsIgnoreCase("m"))) {
                System.out.println("A que hora paso esta moto? (0-23): ");
                hora = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                while(hora < 0 || hora > 23) {
                    System.out.println("El horario debe ser entre 0 y 23: ");
                    hora = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                }
                if(hora >= 9 && hora <= 18) {
                    valoraCobrarMotoPico = (((COSTO_MOTO*50)/100)+COSTO_MOTO);
                    System.out.println("Se le cobrará: " + valoraCobrarMotoPico);
                }else {
                    valoraCobrarMoto = (COSTO_MOTO);
                    System.out.println("Se le cobrará: " + valoraCobrarMoto);
                }
                cont_motos++;
            }
            if(esCamioneta = (vehiculo.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))) {
                System.out.println("A que hora paso esta camioneta? (0-23): ");
                hora = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                while(hora < 0 || hora > 23) {
                    System.out.println("El horario debe ser entre 0 y 23: ");
                    hora = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                }
                if(hora >= 9 && hora <= 18) {
                    valoraCobrarCamionetaPico = (((COSTO_CAMIONETA*50)/100)+COSTO_CAMIONETA);
                    System.out.println("Se le cobrará: " + valoraCobrarCamionetaPico);
                }else {
                    valoraCobrarCamioneta = (COSTO_CAMIONETA);
                    System.out.println("Se le cobrará: " + valoraCobrarCamioneta);
                }
                cont_camionetas++;
            }
            total_vehiculos = (cont_autos+cont_motos+cont_camionetas);
            porcentaje_autos = ((cont_autos/total_vehiculos)*100);
            System.out.println("autos: " + cont_autos);
            System.out.println("motos: " + cont_motos);
            System.out.println("camionetas: " + cont_camionetas);
            cont_patentes++;
        }while(!patente.equalsIgnoreCase("fin"));
        if(cont_patentes == 0) {
            System.out.println("No hubo ingresos.");
        }else {
            recaudacion_total = (valoraCobrarAuto+valoraCobrarAutoPico+valoraCobrarMoto+valoraCobrarMotoPico+valoraCobrarCamioneta+valoraCobrarCamionetaPico);
            System.out.println("La recaudacion total fue de: " + "$" + recaudacion_total);
            System.out.println("el porcentaje de autos es: " + porcentaje_autos + "%");
        }

        
        input.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podrías colocar un punto de ruptura (break) después de solicitar que se ingrese la patente,solo tendrías que inicializar `String patente="";`

```
System.out.println("Ingrese la patente: ");
            patente = input.nextLine();
            //ruptura si se ingresa fin
             if(patente.equalsIgnoreCase("fin")){
                break;
            } 
            System.out.println("Que tipo de vehiculo es? 'a', 'm' o 'c'");
            vehiculo = input.nextLine();
```

si no se puede usar break,una condicional if que evalué si patente es diferente de "fin" para que ejecute código de lo contrario si se ingresa fin salta hasta la ultima parte del código y termina la ejecución

```
   do{ 
           
            System.out.println("Ingrese la patente: ");
            patente = input.nextLine();

            if(!patente.equalsIgnoreCase("fin")){

            System.out.println("Que tipo de vehiculo es? 'a', 'm' o 'c'");
            vehiculo = input.nextLine();
            if(esAuto = (vehiculo.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))) {
                System.out.println("A que hora paso este auto? (0-23): ");
                hora = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                while(hora < 0 || hora > 23) {
                    System.out.println("El horario debe ser entre 0 y 23: ");
                    hora = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                }
                if(hora >= 9 && hora <= 18) {
                    valoraCobrarAutoPico = (((COSTO_AUTO*50)/100)+COSTO_AUTO);
                    System.out.println("Se le cobrará: " + valoraCobrarAutoPico);
                }else {
                        valoraCobrarAuto = (COSTO_AUTO);
                        System.out.println("Se le cobrará: " + valoraCobrarAuto);
                }
                cont_autos++;
            }
            if(esMoto = (vehiculo.equalsIgnoreCase("m"))) {
                System.out.println("A que hora paso esta moto? (0-23): ");
                hora = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                while(hora < 0 || hora > 23) {
                    System.out.println("El horario debe ser entre 0 y 23: ");
                    hora = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                }
                if(hora >= 9 && hora <= 18) {
                    valoraCobrarMotoPico = (((COSTO_MOTO*50)/100)+COSTO_MOTO);
                    System.out.println("Se le cobrará: " + valoraCobrarMotoPico);
                }else {
                    valoraCobrarMoto = (COSTO_MOTO);
                    System.out.println("Se le cobrará: " + valoraCobrarMoto);
                }
                cont_motos++;
            }
            if(esCamioneta = (vehiculo.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))) {
                System.out.println("A que hora paso esta camioneta? (0-23): ");
                hora = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                while(hora < 0 || hora > 23) {
                    System.out.println("El horario debe ser entre 0 y 23: ");
                    hora = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                }
                if(hora >= 9 && hora <= 18) {
                    valoraCobrarCamionetaPico = (((COSTO_CAMIONETA*50)/100)+COSTO_CAMIONETA);
                    System.out.println("Se le cobrará: " + valoraCobrarCamionetaPico);
                }else {
                    valoraCobrarCamioneta = (COSTO_CAMIONETA);
                    System.out.println("Se le cobrará: " + valoraCobrarCamioneta);
                }
                cont_camionetas++;
            }

        }
            total_vehiculos = (cont_autos+cont_motos+cont_camionetas);
            porcentaje_autos = ((cont_autos/total_vehiculos)*100);
            System.out.println("autos: " + cont_autos);
            System.out.println("motos: " + cont_motos);
            System.out.println("camionetas: " + cont_camionetas);
            cont_patentes++;

        }while(!patente.equalsIgnoreCase("fin"));
```

Comment: el profesor no mata si usamos break :/, no es opcion

Comment: que radical el profe xd, edite la respuesta

Comment: ahi si funciono lo del do while,  pero la suma de recaudacion total anda medio rara, a veces se olvida de sumar lo que pagaron algunos vehiculos. Y el porcentaje de autos me da  0% al poner fin (eso siempre me sucedió, que de 0% aun así habiendo pasado autos, motos y camionetas).

Comment: debes revisar tu código, el dinero si aumenta si el porcentaje te sale 0% es por que estas usando int en vez de double ;) ,si te sirvio la respuesta dale check  ✓  ,saludos